# Как воссоздать такую анимацию плавной смены изображений?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

Есть анимация на первом экране сайт - https://travelshift.com/
Это готовая библиотека (если да не подскажите, какая)
Если самопис не подскажите, что почитать/посмотреть на эту тему.

Comment: это WebGL, шейдеры..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , всегда восхищался когда делают подобные анимации, в частности когда разбираются в шейдерах и пишут их самостоятельно, нет ли какой-либо информации о том, как пишутся шейдеры? Я для подобных анимаций использовал библиотеку **ThreeJS**, но как пишутся шейдеры и как в этом разобраться не знаю и по сей день.

Comment: @MoloF я разбирался, копаясь в интернете, это все математика...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , я чего спросил, пришел клиент и яро доказывал, что это простая анимация на сss с моего вопроса с чего такие выводы - вот ответ 'Сказал начальник отдела разработки. Это просто комбинация анимаций состоящая из 3 несложных анимаций, надо всего лишь их обьединить.
Подобные проекты уже у нас были, но сейчас все разработчики на других проектах' , поэтому и спросил.

Comment: @Taras пускай покажут мастер класс =)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mrliZFP.png конкретно этот экземпляр на three.js

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , не поленились и нашли - довольно сильно)

Comment: и эффекты эти, не такие уж несложные, вот тут - несложные https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/jOPQWZV

Comment: @MoloF https://thebookofshaders.com/?lan=ru

Answer (score 9, accepted):

собрал что-то по мотивам:

```js
let s = 600;

document.body.innerHTML +=`
  <canvas id="canvas" width="${s}" height="${s}"></canvas>`;

let actual = 0, v = 0, gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

loadTexture(0, `https://picsum.photos/id/88/${s}/${s}`)
loadTexture(1, `https://picsum.photos/id/77/${s}/${s}`)
addEventListener('touchstart', s => v = 1 === v ? 0 : 1);
addEventListener('click', s => v = 1 === v ? 0 : 1);

let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader(`
  attribute vec2 c;
  
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(c, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision mediump float;

  uniform vec2 size;
  uniform float time;
  uniform float val;

  uniform sampler2D tex0;
  uniform sampler2D tex1;

  void main(void) {

    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / size.xy;
    vec2 c = uv - 0.5;
    float a = atan(c.y, c.x);
    uv = c*(1.-2.*length(c)*(0.5-abs(val-0.5)))+0.5;
    float d = sqrt(sqrt(dot(c, c))) + sin(a*7.)*0.02;
    float v = smoothstep(val+0.1, val - 0.1, d);
    a = 1.0 - val;
    vec2 cs = vec2(cos(a), sin(a));
    vec2 uv2 = (uv-0.5)/sqrt(val)*mat2(cs, -cs.y, cs.x) + 0.5;
    gl_FragColor = mix(
        texture2D(tex1, uv2), 
        texture2D(tex0, uv), 1.0 - v);
  }

`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
  new Float32Array([-1, 3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "c");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

let timeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
let valueLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'val');
let sizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'size');
gl.uniform2f(sizeLocation, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight)
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function loadTexture(i, url) {
  let loader = new Image();
  loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  loader.src = url;
  loader.onload = function() {
    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true)
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0+i);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "tex"+i), i);
  }
}

function draw(t) {
  if (Math.abs(v-actual)>1e-4)
    actual += Math.sign(v-0.5)/100
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeLocation, t / 1000);
  gl.uniform1f(valueLocation, actual);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  let message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n").map((str, i) => ("" + (1 + i))
                   .padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str).join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Не подскажите учебники по вершинным, пиксельным и фрагментным шейдерам? Нашёл только отличный [мини учебник по фрагментным шейдерам](https://thebookofshaders.com/?lan=ru), а по остальным какая-то шляпа в гугле выдаётся.

Comment: @MoloF в целом надо почитать не про шейдеры, а про архитектуру gpu, шейдеры это только часть, которая выполняется на gpu. и кстати пиксельный и фрагментный шейдер это один и тот же шейдер. толкового учебника я не встречал, могу ответить на Ваши конкретные вопросы, сегодня завёл тут чат для этих целей https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106467/webgl-glsl

Comment: И кстати почему то это НЕ работает на планшете