# Возможно ли реализовать такой эффект плавной смены изображений на чистом css?

Tags: css3

Увидел сайт с очень интересным эффектом: https://travelshift.com/

В правом верхнем углу есть круглая кнопка со стрелкой, если нажать на неё начинается нужный эффект,
все мои попытки провальные и кода нету.

Может быть у кого то не будет это отображаться и по этому скину ссылкы на видео в dropbox: [видео](https://www.dropbox.com/s/610hio9wv8axnnf/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE.mp4?dl=0)

Сам эффект начинается после того как нажать на кнопку мышки ..

Можно ли на css получить хотя бы частичную копию ?

Ответы на шейдерах на javascript не нужны

Comment: Какой эффект ? Смены фотографии? Нельзя конечно.

Comment: @hu-fo я понимаю что там canvas или шейдеры ..я делал подобное только чуть чуть другой эффект ..

Comment: @MaximLenksy а что ты на css кроме skew сможешь сделать, что хоть каплю будет напоминать этот эффект? Ничего.

Comment: @hu-fo https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dxYRoo смотри - без js но при наведении ..я эту штуку перепиливал весь день

Comment: Прикольно кстати. Но это ведь далеко не тот эффект. Плюс анимируется ширина и фильтры...мое корыто от таких эффектов и сгореть может )

Comment: @hu-fo я не спорю - но за основу можно взять ...

Comment: почему ты добавил теги, не css?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я подумал что будет не интересно кому то ....на js по любому больше возможностей ..

Comment: там один парень с хабра повторил очень точно этот эффет, правда опяь на gl

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ссылку покажи ..плиз

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/738681

Comment: а вот моя поделка, отличается от ответа 
 на прошлый вопрос https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/eYNbOyL

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нии чего не отличается - это 100% попадание ..я просто думал можно на css этого достичь - пиши ответ но раньше недели не смогу принять его

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у нас блин он лайн уроки -я по этому отвлекаюсь

Comment: нет, ты не понял, я уже тут на стекоферфлоу публиковал ответ на этот вопрос, код там был несколько отличен от моего codepen https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1100338/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне далеко до большой gl славы :))

Comment: хочу заметить, что написание полноэкранных эффектов во фрагментных шейдерах, это не сложно, по сравнению с прорвой возможностей, которые дает gl в целом, хочешь - научу :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ пока не до этого - карантин пройдёт ...будет видно ...я сегодлня второй раз на работу выезжал уже

Answer (score 15, accepted):

У меня получился следующий эффект, реализация которого на основе заготовки автора вопроса. Возможно, что это не совсем именно то, что требуется в вопросе. Сайт по ссылке открыть не могу (санкции), поэтому ориентировался по видео. Чтобы решить задачу полностью и с точностью, готов и дальше двигаться в нужном направлении. И конечно же, коллеги, присоединяйтесь :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.circle').hover(function() {
    $('.circle__inner').addClass('circle__inner__on');
    $('.before').addClass('before__on');
    $('.after').addClass('after__on');
  }, function() {
    $('.circle__inner').addClass('circle__inner__off');
    $('.before').addClass('before__off');
    $('.after').addClass('after__off');
  });
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.circle__inner').removeClass('circle__inner__off').removeClass('circle__inner__on');
    $('.before').removeClass('before__off').removeClass('before__on');
    $('.after').removeClass('after__off').removeClass('after__on');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Background*/

.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://www.nastol.com.ua/pic/201704/1920x1200/nastol.com.ua-216880.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://tapety.tja.pl/obrazki/tja_normalne/208831.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
  transform: translate(-100%) scale(5) rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.before__on {
  transform: translate(-100%) scale(5) rotate(-45deg);
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(10px);
  animation: animate__before__on 8s ease;
}

.after__on {
  transform: translate(0) scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0px);
  animation: animate__after__on 8s ease;
}

.before__off {
  transform: translate(0) scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0px);
  animation: animate__before__off 8s ease;
}

.after__off {
  transform: translate(-100%) scale(5) rotate(-45deg);
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(10px);
  animation: animate__after__off 8s ease;
}

@keyframes animate__before__on {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0) scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%) scale(5) rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
}

@keyframes animate__after__on {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0) scale(5) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0) scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animate__before__off {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0) scale(5) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0) scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animate__after__off {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0) scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%) scale(5) rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
}


/*Progress*/

.circle-size,
.circle,
.circle__mask,
.circle__inner {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.clip-show-left,
.circle__mask.on-left,
.on-right .circle__inner {
  clip: rect(0, 1.5em, 3em, 0);
}

.clip-show-right,
.circle__mask.on-right,
.on-left .circle__inner {
  clip: rect(0, 3em, 3em, 1.5em);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid aliceblue;
}

.circle__mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.circle__holder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle__inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.on-left .circle__inner__on {
  animation: circle-left__on 16s linear;
}

.on-right .circle__inner__on {
  animation: circle-right__on 16s linear;
}

.on-left .circle__inner__off {
  animation: circle-left__off 16s linear;
}

.on-right .circle__inner__off {
  animation: circle-right__off 16s linear;
}

@keyframes circle-left__on {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-right__on {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-left__off {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-right__off {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.circle>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(-25%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 33px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: #111;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #111;
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="after"></div>
  <div class="before"></div>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle__mask on-left">
    <div class="circle__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle__mask on-right">
    <div class="circle__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle__holder"></div>
  <span>Наведи <br> и подержи</span>
</div>
<button>Сбросить</button>
```

Comment: в принципе близко - очень близко - как я и сказал 90% - жирный плюс

Comment: @Sevastopol' Как всегда здорово )))

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант. Сценарий анимации максимально постарался приблизить к оригиналу в вопросе. Но это лишь сценарий, и чего-то мне кажется здесь ещё не хватает. Конечно, такие эффекты с помощью WebGL повторить на CSS вероятнее всего невозможно. Но, есть ещё над чем подумать и работать :))

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.circle').hover(function() {
    $('.circle__inner').addClass('circle__inner__on');
    $('.before').addClass('before__on');
    $('.after').addClass('after__on');
  }, function() {
    $('.circle__inner').addClass('circle__inner__off');
    $('.before').addClass('before__off');
    $('.after').addClass('after__off');
  });
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.circle__inner').removeClass('circle__inner__off').removeClass('circle__inner__on');
    $('.before').removeClass('before__off').removeClass('before__on');
    $('.after').removeClass('after__off').removeClass('after__on');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Background*/

.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://www.nastol.com.ua/pic/201704/1920x1200/nastol.com.ua-216880.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://tapety.tja.pl/obrazki/tja_normalne/208831.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.34s linear;
  transform: scale(5) rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(30px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.before__on {
  transform: scale(0.5) rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(30px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: animate__before__on 2s ease;
}

.after__on {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: animate__after__on 2s ease;
}

.before__off {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: animate__before__off 2s ease;
}

.after__off {
  transform: scale(0.5) rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(30px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: animate__after__off 2s ease;
}

@keyframes animate__before__on {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.1) rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(30px);
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

@keyframes animate__after__on {
  0% {
    transform: scale(5) rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(30px);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animate__before__off {
  0% {
    transform: scale(5) rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(30px);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animate__after__off {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.1) rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(30px);
    z-index: -1;
  }
}


/*Progress*/

.circle-size,
.circle,
.circle__mask,
.circle__inner {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.clip-show-left,
.circle__mask.on-left,
.on-right .circle__inner {
  clip: rect(0, 1.5em, 3em, 0);
}

.clip-show-right,
.circle__mask.on-right,
.on-left .circle__inner {
  clip: rect(0, 3em, 3em, 1.5em);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid aliceblue;
}

.circle__mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.circle__holder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle__inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.on-left .circle__inner__on {
  animation: circle-left__on 4s linear;
}

.on-right .circle__inner__on {
  animation: circle-right__on 4s linear;
}

.on-left .circle__inner__off {
  animation: circle-left__off 4s linear;
}

.on-right .circle__inner__off {
  animation: circle-right__off 4s linear;
}

@keyframes circle-left__on {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-right__on {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-left__off {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-right__off {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.circle>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(-25%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 33px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: #111;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #111;
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="after"></div>
  <div class="before"></div>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle__mask on-left">
    <div class="circle__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle__mask on-right">
    <div class="circle__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle__holder"></div>
  <span>Наведи <br> и подержи</span>
</div>
<button>Сбросить</button>
```